# A simple local SMTP server

Tags: java, email, testing, smtp

I want to test a Java code for sending email. I don't want to use any commercial mail client or connect to any external mail providers (like Gmail or Yahoo). I would like to know if there is any software which allows a user to configure dummy email addresses and server (locally) which can be used in my software to send and receive mails. I just want to test the functionality of the Java code.

Comment: Check this.. http://enbiso.github.io/dummy-smtp-server/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For email testing, try Dumbster. From their page:

> The Dumbster is a very simple fake SMTP server designed for unit and
>   system testing applications that send email messages. It responds to
>   all standard SMTP commands but does not deliver messages to the user.
>   The messages are stored within the Dumbster for later extraction and
>   verification.
>
> The Dumbster slots itself very easily into your testing strategy. As
>   long as your application talks to an email server using SMTP then the
>   Dumbster can be used to test the application with no code changes.

Various forks exist since the original page is no longer available:

- https://github.com/kirviq/dumbster
- https://github.com/rjo1970/dumbster

More can be found using a [Github Search](https://github.com/search?q=dumbster&type=Repositories)

Comment: Ah, that's the other one I was trying to remember!  I knew I'd recognize it as soon as I saw it, but I just couldn't come up with the name.

Comment: Dumbster is [broken](http://sourceforge.net/p/dumbster/bugs/15/).

Comment: _As a side note:_ there are [several _forks_](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dumbster&type=) of the original "Dumbster" that improve its functionality in different ways.

Comment: Could you update the link in this answer? The original one redirects to agoda (a hotel booking web site) now. https://github.com/kirviq/dumbster and https://github.com/rjo1970/dumbster both look promising to me but I haven't tried either of them yet.

Comment: I found original link does not work anymore. Here there is a fork that works for me: https://github.com/kirviq/dumbster

Comment: try greenmail library!

Comment: I'm a little late for this question, but I just released smtp4j (https://github.com/ctabin/smtp4j) which is an improved API based on dumbster :-)

Answer (score 19):

I prefer [Fake SMTP](http://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/screenshots.html) for this. It's a desktop app (packed into jar file). Since it is written in Java, you can run it both from Linux/Mac/Windows

Comment: This is non-invasive and clean solution, at least with spring applications

Answer (score 10):

You can use Wiser in the [SubEthaSMTP](https://github.com/voodoodyne/subethasmtp) library, Wiser's purpose is exactly what you want, unit testing.

Comment: Wiser sample code: http://code.google.com/p/subethasmtp/wiki/Wiser

Comment: Also broken, when my unit test sends 2 html emails wiser receives 3 somehow. GreenMail handles that correctly, fortunately.

Comment: okutane: I guess you sent two mails with three recipients in total. The Wiser API returns mails by recipients. It is indeed not in the last released version, but the trunk contains an updated JavaDoc to make this more obvious:
"The number of mail transactions and the number of mails may be different. If a message is received with multiple recipients in a single mail
transaction, then the list will contain more WiserMessage instances, one
for each recipient."

Comment: @HontváriLevente: no, that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 9):

Try [GreenMail](http://www.icegreen.com/greenmail/).  It's geared towards JUnit usage, but it should do what you need.  You can run it in a JBoss instance or have your JUnit tests send mail to themselves, depending on your specific needs.

There are a few other similar bits of software out there, but that's the one I've used and was reasonably happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

on Leopard you can start a  Local SMTP Server (Postfix) on OS-X Leopard

```
sudo vi /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
```

before the closing  tag at the end:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key> <true/> <key>KeepAlive</key> <true/>
```

then start the thing with

```
sudo postfix start
```

now you check wheter the service is running with:

```
telnet localhost 25
```

Answer (score 3):

The **javamail-file-transport** saves emails to files instead of sending them through SMTP server.

See the **[javaMail extensions](https://github.com/m-szalik/javamail/wiki)** project on GitHub.

It adds **file transport** that allows:

- save mails to files in `text` format instead of sending them
- save mails to files in `mbox` format instead of sending them
- add log info instead of sending email

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/) a few times, and I can recommend it.

Comment: Mailnest.io is a much better and affordable solution for email testing.

Answer (score 1):

**Option A**.
amazing docker
https://hub.docker.com/r/mailhog/mailhog/
(gitHub - https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog)
This docker has two ports:
One port for sending SMTP e-mails (smtp://0.0.0.0:1025/)
A second port to the e-mail display on the web (http://0.0.0.0:8025/)

run docker:
`docker pull mailhog/mailhog`
`docker run --name=mailhog -d -p 1025:1025 -p 8025:8025 mailhog/mailhog`

**Option B**.
if you use with bamboo.mailer
add `adapter: Bamboo.LocalAdapter`
see [Bamboo.SentEmailViewerPlug.](https://hexdocs.pm/bamboo/Bamboo.SentEmailViewerPlug.html)

Comment: see [A Test Mail Server for a PHP Docker Container](https://blog.philipphauer.de/test-mail-server-php-docker-container/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [smtp4dev](http://smtp4dev.codeplex.com/). Please find out more details [here](http://amitergupta.blogspot.in/2015/10/testing-email-functionality-in.html).

Comment: It was the best fake mail server I have, wondering that page says it contains a virus!

Answer (score 0):

[use the Aspirin](https://github.com/masukomi/aspirin)
From the docs: Aspirin is an embeddable send-only SMTP server for Java developers.