# Generate MailSendException with fake smtp server

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jakarta-mail

I need to test some component that sends an email batch using a Spring MailSender instance. The method "send" throws a MailSendException when the provided destination address is not well formed, something like myAddressgmail.com (Note that I'm not pretending that my smtp server know if the address really exist in the destination host, just talking about structure). In fact, this is what happens when using my real smtp server.

To mock the smtp server I've tried Dumbster and GreenMail and here appears the problem. These fake smtp servers don't check if the address is well formed, so the MailSendException is not thrown. I need to throw this exception in order to test the exception handling.

Comment: It should be fairly easy to modify Dumbster to return an error if it sees an address of a certain type.

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599791/a-simple-local-smtp-server/22043597#22043597

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a mocking library like [Mockito](http://mockito.googlecode.com) or [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/).

Then you can do something like:

```
MailSender mockSender = mock(MailSender.class);
YourSMTPServer server = new YourSMTPServer(mockSender);

when(mockSender.send(...)).thenThrow(new MailSendException(...));

// then invoke the method on your server that calls MailSender.send() and
// assert it does what you want it to do when an exception is encountered
```

Comment: I've missed this approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use mailnest.io for your email testing. In the platform there is an error mode which you can switch on to mock an error response from the server.