# Sending email from localhost using Java

Tags: java, email

Is there a way that I can implement a code that would setup a temporary SMTP server on users computer, send an email and then terminate itself?

I'd like to avoid having to enter credentials for a email account, which I have to do when using Javamail...

EDIT: I need to distribute that program among users and enable them to send me an email by just clicking a button. I have to be able to setup a server with my program without using outside tools, and I have to be able to do it on any computer (if it's connected to the internet, of course).

This needs to be easy to do for my user, else it looses it's point... If a user will have to install aditional software to make it work, there's no point in doing it...

EDIT2: I'm trying to avoid authentication, because Java is relatively easy to decompile. I could jumble it up using some tools, but that not 100% safe. If I enter any emails or passwords, a person determined enough could get to them and mess up my sending address...

EDIT3: No cross-posting so here:
http://www.java-forums.org/networking/80389-getting-files-user-computer-google-cloud-drive.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599791/a-simple-local-smtp-server

Comment: And here's another one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaemailserver/

Comment: First comment is for testing, it won't work for me. Second one is external software, which again, won't cut it.

Comment: For the first one I agree, but the second one, it's an external software, with source code (BSD-License), so you could use the core classes and strip the gui... Would need to check how time consuming it is, but it's still an option...

Comment: And about the first post, check the other options (GreenMail and SubEthaSMTP)

Comment: Would that really send the email to desired address, or only emulate the action?

Comment: @Martin? I think it won't work...